# Trouble installing Ubuntu through Rufus

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, rufus

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Flash Drive but a message pops up after I agree for Rufus to format the drive that says "access denied". I am the administrator, so I do not know why it would tell me this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related to http://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/459

Is the .iso file you're trying to install already located on the USB drive?

If so, don't do that. The first thing Rufus does is to format your USB device, erasing all data, so the .iso file needs to be on your hard drive (or anywhere but the USB device).

Then you should be able to use Rufus to properly create the USB stick, using the .iso file on your hard drive.